# Restricting access by IP address to wp-admin and wp-login.php on Azure Wordpress on Linux

Tags: wordpress, azure, nginx

Using Azure Wordpress for Linux Web App, I'm trying to modify the nginx conf.d file to restrict access to wp-login.php and wp-admin directory by IP address. The directives that I'm trying to use either seem to completely allow access or completely deny access, it does not seem to respect allow x.x.x.x; at all.

Here is the code that I've placed in my server block:

```
    location ~ ^(wp-admin|wp-login.php) {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
            index index.html index.htm index.php;
            allow x.x.x.x;
            deny all;
            }
```

If I only have the deny all; directive, everything returns a 403 forbidden error. If I put in the allow directive, I can access it from any IP address and it never seems to throw an error.

I've noticed in my logs that this is showing up:

```
    278#278: *25 access forbidden by rule, client: 172.19.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /wp-admin HTTP/1.1", host: "myhostname.com"
```

and that this precedes my server block in the default.conf file:

```
    upstream php {
            #server unix:/tmp/php-cgi.socket;
            server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
```

Is these something going on that basically makes all my inbound traffic appear to nginx as coming from the same IP address? Is there any way to "pass that down" ?

Here is the default.conf file:

```
    upstream php {
            server unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            #server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    server {
            listen 80;
            ## Your website name goes here.
            server_name _;
            ## Your only path reference.
            root /home/site/wwwroot;
            ## This should be in your http block and if it is, it's not needed here.
            index index.php index.html;

            location = /favicon.ico {
                    log_not_found off;
                    access_log off;
            }

            location = /robots.txt {
                    allow all;
                    log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
            }

      # Add locations of phpmyadmin here.

      # Disable sendfile as per https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/virtual
      sendfile off;

      set $skip_cache 0;

      # POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
      if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $skip_cache 1;
      }
      if ($query_string != "") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
      }

      # Don't cache uris containing the following segments
      if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
      }

      # Don't use the cache for logged in users or recent commenters
      if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
      }

      # Don't cache WooCommerce URLs
      # Cart widgets are still a problem: https://github.com/emcniece/docker-wordpress/issues/3
      if ($request_uri ~* "/(cart|checkout|my-account)/*$") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
      }
            location / {
                    # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
                    # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
            }

            location ~ \.php$ {
                    #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
                    include fastcgi.conf;
                    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                    fastcgi_pass php;

        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_cache WORDPRESS;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 60m;
            }

            location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                    expires max;
                    log_not_found off;
            }
```

I started noticing today that I can see the IP address that I want under the PHP variable of $_SERVER['HTTP_X_CLIENT_IP'] --- Is there a way to test that under the allow/deny options, or to override the value that allow/deny looks at to use this other value? For example:

```
if ($http_x_client_ip != x.x.x.x) {
                return 403;
        }
```

Comment: Are you using a load balancer?

And can you post your whole nginx config - order matters

Comment: Hi Tim, I edited the original post. I think one challenge I'm going to face here is that the default.conf file in the Azure Web App would get overwritten every time the app restarts. Ideally, there would be some way to have a persistent file store with the configuration file that would also allow me to parse the end user's IP address.

Comment: Phil - did you figure out a way to persist changes to the nginx.conf?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to define and map your list of whitelisting ip address to $http_x_client_ip outside the server section of your default.conf as below

```
map $http_x_client_ip $address_filter {
        default       off;

        1.2.3.4     on;
        2.3.4.*     on;
        3.*.4.*     on;
}
```

And then replace your code

```
location ~ ^(wp-admin|wp-login.php) {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        allow x.x.x.x;
        deny all;
        }
```

with a syntax format like below

```
location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login\.php) {
            if ($address_filter = off) {
                    return 403;
            }
    }
```

Assuming the result of your mapped ip is represented as `$address_filter`.

Your modified default.conf should look like this

```
upstream php {
    server unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
    
map $http_x_client_ip $address_filter {
    default       off;

    1.2.3.4     on;
    2.3.4.*     on;
    3.*.4.*     on;
}
    
server {
    listen 80;
    ## Your website name goes here.
    server_name _;
    ## Your only path reference.
    root /home/site/wwwroot;
    ## This should be in your http block and if it is, it's not needed here.
    index index.php index.html;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # Add locations of phpmyadmin here.

    # Disable sendfile as per https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/virtual
    sendfile off;

    set $skip_cache 0;

    # POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }
    if ($query_string != "") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    # Don't cache uris containing the following segments
    if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    # Don't use the cache for logged in users or recent commenters
    if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    # Don't cache WooCommerce URLs
    # Cart widgets are still a problem: https://github.com/emcniece/docker-wordpress/issues/3
    if ($request_uri ~* "/(cart|checkout|my-account)/*$") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }
    
    location / {
        # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
        # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login\.php) {
        if ($address_filter = off) {
                return 403;
        }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass php;

        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_cache WORDPRESS;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 60m;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** The `$http_x_client_ip` will get you the absolute client ip. The (*) asterisk in those sample ips allows you to define a wildcard number in your ip if required. You also need to use your whitelist ips in place of the sample ip declaration.